# How to access node's file from FlinkSessionJob?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Recently installed Flink kubernetes operator in linux system. I created yaml file for FlinkDeployment and FlinkSessionJob. FlinkDeployment was created successfully but FlinkSessionJob cann't be created because of not able to access jarURI path.
Here is FlinkDeployment and FlinkSessionJob file.

FlinkDeployement-abcd.yaml:

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: fbp-abcd-deployment
  namespace: dev
  ....
  ....
```

FlinkSessionJob-abcd.yaml

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkSessionJob
metadata:
  name: fbp-abcd-job
spec:
  deploymentName: fbp-abcd-deployment
  job:
    jarURI: file:/home/abcd/fbp-acc-lc.jar # which are present in Node
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: savepoint
    entryClass: com.abcd.accountmgmt.FlinkMain
    allowNonRestoredState: true
```

Here is FlinkSessionJob object fb-abcd-job's error

> Status:   Error:
> {"type":"org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.exception.ReconciliationException","message":"java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /home/abcd/fbp-acc-lc.jar (No such file or
> directory)","throwableList":[{"type":"java.io.FileNotFoundException","message":"/home/abcd/fbp-acc-lc.jar
> (No such file or directory)"}]}

Please help me how to access node's file system from FlinkSessionJob.

I was trying to access the file, which are in node, from FlinkSessionJob. I am expecting the flinksessionjob to access the node's filesystem.

Node has no access to internet except organisation's jfrog artifactory which require user credentials.